# A "quantum" identity: in search of a proof -Part II

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, enumerative-combinatorics, combinatorial-identities, q-analogs

As usual, denote $[n]_q=1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1}=\frac{\,\,1-q^n}{1-q}$ and $[n]_q!=[1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q$. Furthermore, we write
$$\binom{n}k_q=\frac{[n]_q!}{[k]_q!\cdot[n-k]_q!}.$$
As a follow up on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270115/an-interesting-identity-in-search-of-a-proof-part-i), I propose a $q$-analogue identity.

> **Question.** Can you show that
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^nq^{(y-n+1)k}\binom{x+k}k_q\binom{y-k}{n-k}_q
> =\sum_{k=0}^nq^{n-k}\binom{x+y-k}{n-k}_q\,\,\,?$$

It would be great if we can see alternative proofs? I've a bias for combinatorial arguments. :-)

Comment: it is interesting for $x=0$: we get that two different $q$-analogs of $\sum \binom{y-k}{n-k}$ are equal.

Comment: That's a cute observation, Fedor!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both sides are equal to $\binom{x+y+1}{n}_q$. This enumerates lattice paths in an $n\times (x+y-n+1)$ rectangle, according to the area statistic. We will assume that these paths start at $(0,0)$ and end at $(x+y-n+1,n)$, and they are only directed East or North. Here are two ways to enumerate it:

**First count**: For each path there will be a unique $k$, so it has an East step of the form $(x,k)\to (x+1,k)$. The area generating function of these paths is precisely
$$q^{y-n+1}\binom{x+k}{k}_q\binom{y-k}{n-k}_q.$$
Now, summing over all possible $k$, we enumerate all paths in the rectangle.

**Second count**: For each path there will be a unique $k$ so that it has an East step $(x+y-n,k)\to (x+y-n+1,k)$. Similarly the generating function of the areas of these paths is
$$q^{n-k}\binom{x+y-k}{n-k}_q$$
and just like above, summing over all possible $k$ enumerates all paths.

Comment: Could you give a reference for these area generating functions?

Comment: They are all immediate corollaries of counting lattice paths in a rectangle. Drawing a picture helps a lot :)

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi:  Very pleasant.

Answer (score 11):

If we substitute $y:=v+n$ in the identity, the LHS becomes a convolution of two similar sequences,
$$\sum_{k=0}^nq^{(v+1)k}\binom{x+k}{k}_q \binom{v+(n-k)}{n-k}_q =\sum_{k=0}^n q^{n-k}\binom{x+v+n-k}{n-k}_q \, .$$

In terms of the known series $$f_x(z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x+k}{k}_q \,z^k=\prod_{k=0}^x{1\over1-q^kz}$$ the identity reads
$$f_x(q^{v+1}z)\cdot f_v(z)={1\over1-z}\cdot f_{x+v}(qz)=f_{x+v+1}(z)\, ,$$
which is straightforward.

($\prod_{k=v+1}^{v+1+x}\,\prod_{k=0}^{v}=\prod_{k=1}^{v+1+x}\,\prod_{k=0}^{0}=\prod_{k=0}^{v+x+1}$)
$$*$$
*rmk.* Note that the latter also gives again the first identity of Gjergji's answer, since  $[z^n]f_{x+v+1}(z)=\binom{ x+v+1+n}{n}_q=\binom{ x+y+1}{n}_q$.

Comment: You got to do what you wanted in Part I. :-)

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it partially ;)

Answer (score 7):

Actually this is a partial case of $q$-Vandermonde identity.
In the notation $$[a;b]_q^n:=(a-b)(a-qb)\dots (a-q^{n-1}b)=a^n(b/a;q)_n,$$ as in [this terminology question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225115/notation-for-a-ba-qb-dots-a-qn-1b), we have 
$$
[a;c]_q^n=\sum {\binom{n}{k}}_q[a;b]_q^{n-k}\,[b;c]_q^{k},
$$
which is an equivalent form of [$q$-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Vandermonde_identity).

Substituting $a=q^{n-y-1}$, $b=1$, $c=q^{x+1}$ we get $$\sum_{k=0}^nq^{(y-n+1)k}\binom{x+k}k_q\binom{y-k}{n-k}_q=\binom{x+y+1}n_q,$$
replacing $x,y$ to $x+y-n,n$ (and $k$ to $n-k$ in the sum) we get that RHS also equals $\binom{x+y+1}n_q$.

Comment: This is also cool.